# Why can only see one node after reboot the primary node in a cluster with pacemaker and corosync?

Tags: high-availability, pacemaker, corosync

I created two nodes on CentOS 7:

- node1: 192.168.0.1
- node2: 192.168.0.2

Installed such tools:

```
# yum install -y pacemaker corosync pcs crmsh
```

Also did load balancer with HAProxy.

After I did all the things well, I reboot node1 to test high availability. When node1 booted, from this way can only see one node:

```
# pcs status corosync
```

This can see two nodes:

```
# crm status
```

But the other one is `UNCLEAN`!

```
Stack: corosync
Current DC: node1 (version 1.1.15-11.el7_3.5-e174ec8) - partition WITHOUT quorum

2 nodes and 0 resources configured

Node node2: UNCLEAN (offline)
Online: [ node1 ]

No resources
```

From node2 to check status, also the another one is `UNCLEAN`!

```
Stack: corosync
Current DC: node2 (version 1.1.15-11.el7_3.5-e174ec8) - partition WITHOUT quorum

2 nodes and 0 resources configured

Node node1: UNCLEAN (offline)
Online: [ node2 ]

No resources
```

How to deal with it?

---

## Addition

I did this:

```
# pcs property set stonith-enabled=false
```

The corosync config:

```
totem {
    version: 2
    secauth: off
    cluster_name: lbcluster
    transport: udpu
}

nodelist {
    node {
        ring0_addr: node1
        nodeid: 1
    }

    node {
        ring0_addr: node2
        nodeid: 2
    }
}

quorum {
    provider: corosync_votequorum
    two_node: 1
}

logging {
    to_logfile: yes
    logfile: /var/log/cluster/corosync.log
    to_syslog: yes
}
```

Comment: first of all, you need to share your cluster configuration with us, if you would like to find some that can help you

Comment: Add your pacemaker and corosync config. The nodes aren't communicating correctly. Do you have STONITH enabled?

Comment: @c4f4t0r I added corosync config to the question.

Comment: @Lenniey I have disabled that. Added the operation to the question.

Comment: please add the complete output of `crm status`

Comment: @Lenniey Edited.

Comment: You sure about your DNS? So that `node1` and `node2` cann access each other (and themselves) on both nodes? Nothing in the logs?

Comment: @cloud_cloud how did you reboot the node1? using reboot command or a hard reboot?

Comment: @c4f4t0r Used `reboot` command.

Comment: 1: be sure the dns is working and configure your fencing.

Comment: @c4f4t0r I think the reason was I set this one: `pcs property set stonith-enabled=true`

Comment: @Lenniey I think the reason was I set this one: `pcs property set stonith-enabled=true`

Comment: @cloud_cloud erm...is it working now or what? If you don't have a proper STONITH device, it shouldn't be configured. I assume your fencing is / was wrong.

Comment: @Lenniey I didn't try this issue now because of busy to do other thing. I think if I retry to set servers from 0 with right config will works well. Now I am just doing the test.

Comment: @cloud_cloud `UNCLEAN` usually means that a fence was attempted and failed. You said that you disabled fencing; did you restart Pacemaker afterwards? That would have cleared any `UNCLEAN` status.

EDIT: meant to ask more: Are you letting UDP 5404 and 5405 through the firewall? Those are the ports that Corosync will want to use to communicate.

Comment: @MattKereczman You are right. The reason was the firewall! I added 5404 and 5405 UDP port: `iptables -I INPUT -m state --state NEW -p udp -m multiport --dports 5404,5405 -j ACCEPT`, `iptables -I OUTPUT -m state --state NEW -p udp -m multiport --sports 5404,5405 -j ACCEPT`, `service iptables save`, and stop/start all cluster: `pcs cluster stop --all`, `pcs cluster start --all`. The cluster works! All the nodes can been seen and all of them online! Could you write your suggest as a answer? I will accept it.

Comment: @cloud_cloud done! Thanks for marking your solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let UDP 5404 and 5405 through the firewall; those are the ports that Corosync will want to use to communicate by default.